# SSRS with Oracle, returning ref_cursor when given parameters in a SP

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I'm working on converting some SQLServer reports to Oracle for SSRS and got the first one to work correctly.

Now i'm working on the second one and the only difference is that it has input parameters. When I add these parameters into the SP it returns a ref cursor. When I take them out and just do the select, it returns data.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "getGriefDetails" (o_rc OUT sys_refcursor, inSource IN VARCHAR2,
inTable IN VARCHAR2, inCategory in VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
open o_rc for        

Select * from ERRORDATALOG   
WHERE (((inSource = 'ALL') AND (SOURCESYSTEM like '%')) OR (SOURCESYSTEM = inSource))
AND
(((inTable = 'ALL') AND (TABLENAME like '%')) OR (TABLENAME = inTable))
AND
(((inCategory = 'ALL') AND (GRIEFTYPE like '%')) OR (GRIEFTYPE = inCategory))
Order By SOURCESYSTEM, GRIEFTYPE, TABLENAME;

end;​
```

When this is the sproc, I get this as a result

[image: Results]

However when I just do

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "getGriefDetails" (o_rc OUT sys_refcursor, inSource IN VARCHAR2,
    inTable IN VARCHAR2, inCategory in VARCHAR2) AS
    BEGIN
    open o_rc for        

    Select * from ERRORDATALOG;
end;
```

I get data. The only difference is that I have a where clause with parameters. Am I not setting my cursor correctly?

Comment: Not sure why it's not working. I usually put my IN parameters first and my OUT parameters second. You could rephrase "SOURCESYSTEM like '%'" as "SOURCESYSTEM IS NOT NULL", or omit it entirely. Have you tried breaking the query down into smaller pieces, e.g. just "WHERE SOURCESYSTEM = inSource"?

Comment: You don't seem to be specifying a length for your VARCHAR2 parameters.

Comment: @criticalfix I've removed the entire where clause as well as just putting pieces in. The query works when I run it on the DB but not from SSRS.

Comment: @tgolisch I've never actually set limits on my varchar2 parameters and have never run into an issue with it before. I'll try changing it to see if that helps.